# Attachement not working for MimeMessageHelper Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying mail with zip attachment using SpringFramework.However everytime mail is coming without attachment and mail is also coming with out subject and in improper format.Please find below give sample mail received

```
-----=_Part_0_26427166.1408022473482
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_Part_1_7846309.1408022473566"

------=_Part_1_7846309.1408022473566
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi,

The attached spreadsheet contains a attachment

Please do not hesitate to contact us on the details below with any queries.

Many thanks for your assistance.



------=_Part_1_7846309.1408022473566--

------=_Part_0_26427166.1408022473482
Content-Type: application/zip; name=Details.zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Details.zip


81oAzlM+ZGz7u+8GiaN9S+kXWndHm82/62wMeRMcrP4yA64ihuMPk6YuvIpaFubSkjhgt9f6GMlK
nSLtW3zWKKdcMyO1WjAqgpobIAfRKoub5rd8kRhvsp28x9cblrN9CewpHTkJq4jVkKcRU1Cyz5K5
==
------=_Part_0_26427166.1408022473482--
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to send email in my application:

```
private String from;
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
public void send(String to, String subject, String vt, String[] files, Map<String, Object> model) {
    MimeMessage msg=mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, "UTF-8");
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setFrom(from);
        helper.setText(VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, vt, "UTF-8", model), true);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        FileSystemResource file;
        if(files!=null) {
            //add attachments
            for(String f : files ) {
                file = new FileSystemResource(new File(f));
                helper.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
            }
        }
        mailSender.send(msg);
    } catch(MessagingException me) {
        log.error("Cannot send email message");
    }
}
```

So you can compare with your code